# Javascript config file with business logic for all user actions

Tags: javascript, configuration-files

My question may be little confuse you.

Actually I am searching internet for a standard technology to do the below:

1. Write a config file (JSON or .js) which includes all business logic.
2. Javascript will load that config file and it has to do all the actions specified in the config file.

Sample config file

```
"loginConfig":
[
    "#Submit-button",
    "click",
    {
        "perform": "LoginAction",
        "username": "#input-username",
        "password": "#input-password"
    }
]
```

My requirement is, A javascript library should load this config file and it has to do the below actions

1. When 'Submit' button pressed
2. Read the input (text boxes) values from "#input-username" and "#input-password"
3. And call the function "LoginAction" with the values read from step 2.

I have written a simple .js file to read this config file and do the same action as described above, but I want to know whether this kind of approach (concept) already available or not.

**WHY IT IS REQUIRED?**

In our web development, most of the time we are keep repeating the same JS code to do the below:

1. Click button1 enable textbox1
2. Click button2 disable textbox2
3. Click link1 open something
4. etc.,

**Why don't we have some common JS library to do the above basic things by reading the Config file?**

Comment: This sounds to me like something you would need to write in js using event handlers. It is possible to write a function to do this particular task though.

Comment: A config file that has business logic... I think we call that "Javascript".

Comment: Sam- Yes I have written my own .js file, but I am looking for a standard approach, for example, this kind of feature may be supported in JQuery or some other JS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Having a config file in JSON format is a good idea.

Having a JSON file as a definition for "all business logic" requires a JavaScript framework because the rules can be quite complex. Not everyone uses the same framework, so this will have obvious limitations per application. Where is no one-size-fits all solution, but there is progress being made on this front.

One good example of this "in the wild" is [Sencha's EXT framework](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/). A lot of what it does can be defined in JSON config files and it does have a lot of what you want to do built-in, but it will still require you to write your own code to support the business logic you define.